# C++ regex for unsigned string type

Tags: c++, regex

Visual C++ 2017:
I use unsigned strings:

```
typedef basic_string<unsigned char> ustring;
```

This works ok but when I try to use regex the same way compilation throws a lot of errors which I don't understand:

```
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

typedef basic_regex<unsigned char> uregex;

int main()
{
    uregex ur;
}
```

I get

```
error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::regex_traits<unsigned char>'
```

I suspect there need to be a typedef for regex_traits but I don't know how to define that.

Comment: Are you including `<regex>`?

Comment: Provide a [mcve]

Comment: Of course I do that.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a reasonable question. Minimal Reproducible Example included.

Comment: @Johnny The code compiles fine on [GCC](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sYCYgz1GmEhcLn2O) but not on [Clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5PvrM9hYKzR6XEoN).

Comment: From [`regex_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_traits): `Two specializations of std::regex_traits are defined by the standard library: std::regex_traits<char> std::regex_traits<wchar_t> These specializations make it possible to use std::basic_regex<char> (aka std::regex) and std::basic_regex<wchar_t> (aka std::wregex). To use std::basic_regex with other character types (for example, char32_t), a user-provided trait class must be used.`

Answer (score 0):

`basic_regex` is defined like this: ([[re.regex]](http://eel.is/c++draft/re.regex))

```
template <class CharT, class Traits = regex_traits<CharT>>
class basic_regex;
```

Here, you instantiate `regex_traits<unsigned char>`.  Per [[re.traits]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/re.traits#1):

> The specializations `regex_­traits<char>` and
>   `regex_­traits<wchar_­t>` shall be valid and shall meet the
>   requirements for a regular expression traits class ([re.req]).

In other words, `regex_traits<unsigned char>` may or may not be valid.  It appears that your implementation does not provide such a definition.  Incidentally, the code compiles fine on [GCC](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sYCYgz1GmEhcLn2O) but not on [Clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5PvrM9hYKzR6XEoN).

There is no portable way to use `basic_regex` with `unsigned char`, based on the following proof.

> Proof: suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that we use `basic_regex<unsigned char, Traits>`, where `Traits` is a *regular expression trait* ([[re.req]](http://eel.is/c++draft/re.req)).  Then `Traits::string_type` is `basic_string<unsigned char>` ([[tab:re.req]](http://eel.is/c++draft/re.req#tab:re.req)), which is equivalent to `basic_string<unsigned char, char_traits<unsigned char>>`.  However, `char_traits<unsigned char>` is not guaranteed to be available ([[char.traits.specializations]](http://eel.is/c++draft/char.traits.specializations)), and we are not allowed to provide our own explicit specialization because `unsigned char` is not a program-defined type ([[namespace.std]](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.std#2)), so there is no portable way to use `char_traits<unsigned char>`.  This contradiction suggests that our initial assumption is wrong.  Therefore, we have shown that there is no portable way to use `basic_regex` with `unsigned char`.

Comment: I don't need a portable solution. I just need a basic_regex<unsigned char>

Comment: @Johnny `basic_regex<unsigned char>` doesn't exist.

Comment: Precisely. Please see my original question.

Comment: @Johnny Yeah, the problem is that you cannot define a conforming regex trait for `unsigned char`.

Comment: @Johnny how did you fix this?