# How to do a regex on an unsigned char array? C++

Tags: c++

I have an unsigned character array that I want to perform a regex on, I do not want to create it as a character array, nor do I want to construct an std::string from it. Is there any way I can do this with the standard library?

```
#include <regex>

std::regex handler("b");
unsigned char data[4] = {'a','b','c','d'};
std::smatch match;

// how to correctly use this function with 'data'?
std::regex_search(std::begin(data),std::end(data),match,handler);
```

Comment: `regex_search` is templated over `CharT`. I'm not sure there's anything special about using it on an `unsigned char` array as compared to another range of characters. I suppose you'll need to change the type of `match` to `std::match_results<unsigned char*>`.

Comment: @NathanPierson Care to emphasize for this case?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @NathanPierson What would a working example look like?

Comment: Well, I'm able to get a version working on MSVC, but it looks like GCC and Clang complain that I also need to make it so that `handler` is of a matching type (so `std::basic_regex<unsigned char>`). More of a pain than I realized to make everything else _also_ use `unsigned char` as the underlying character type. Are you _sure_ you can't convert `data`?

Comment: @NathanPierson I could reinterpret the data, but I don't want to construct anything or change the original array type. I've also looked at ```std::string_view```, but the regex functions don't accept those as arguments.

Comment: Related: [C++ regex for unsigned string type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57177343/9716597).  Basically, using `std::basic_regex` with `unsigned char` requires `std::char_traits<unsigned char>`, which doesn't always exist.  `reinterpret_cast` I guess.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding things but I don't see how this can work with the given contents of `data`. `regex` searches string data for string data, doesn't it? The content of `data` isn't actually string --- or character --- data regardless of the signed-ness. How is a regex of `"3"` going to match against numeric data `{1,2,3,4}`?

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with `std::string_view` a bit, I got a solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <regex>

int main() {
    std::regex reg("bc");
    unsigned char arry[4] = {'a','b','c','d'};
    std::cmatch match;
    std::string_view view(reinterpret_cast<char*>(arry));

    // matches and prints 1
    std::cout << std::regex_search(view.begin(),view.end(), match, reg);

    return 0;
}
```

(Note that the regex might not actually match on systems that don't store character arrays in little-endian byte order)